# Is there a brand of DDR4-2666 by SPD?

Tags: memory, pc, intel

Looking to build an i9-9900X system. According to Intel, RAM should be DDR4-2666 (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/x-series/i9-9900x.html).

I never overclock.

The problem with the RAM vendors is, they do not advertise the real (SPD) frequency, which is much lower than the one advertised. For example, I could find RAM advertised to run at 3200, but according to the manufacturer specification, SPD frequency is as low as 2133.
Instead, higher frequencies are stored in XMP profiles, but that's a cheat because it basically means overclocking (also, the voltage is higher than 1.2V)

**So is there any RAM brand that really runs at 2666, by SPD?**

The closest I could find is some Kingston memory that runs at 2400, so I'm thinking to go with it if I can't find a real one. It has a 2666 setting in one of the XMP profiles, and my reasoning is to overclock as little as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to confirm: you are not confusing data rate with clock frequency, are you? Since the **double** in DDR means that data rate is double clock frequency. Can you give an example of such datasheet?

Comment: Ok, turned out I'm uniformed. Will have to read JEDEC docs once I'm able to do so.

Comment: @Jan Dorniak: Both this: https://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX430C15PB3K4_64.pdf and this: https://www.corsair.com/eu/en/Categories/Products/Memory/dominator-rgb-config/p/CMT64GX4M4C3000C15#tab-tech-specs are advertised as DDR4-3000, but according to the specs the SPD speed is lower.

Comment: I was under the impression the only way you get those higher clocks means you have to overclock it. This question seems a bit off-topic though.

Answer (score 1):

This might a little late, but I was searching for the same thing and came across these which were SPD-26666 out of the box:
VENGEANCE® RGB PRO 32GB (2 x 16GB) DDR4 DRAM 3200MHz C16 AMD Ryzen Memory Kit — Black

https://www.corsair.com/eu/en/Categories/Products/Memory/Vengeance-PRO-RGB-Black/p/CMW32GX4M2Z3200C16#tab-tech-specs

They can be bought on Amazon!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following is available in both 8GB & 16GB sizes:

G.SKILL Aegis 8GB (1 * 8GB) DDR4 2666 MHz CL19-19-19-43 1.20V Desktop Memory RAM - F4-2666C19S-8GIS